# Why is my get_post_meta always empty

Tags: php, post-meta, wp-mail

I made this action hook which will send an email to the users every time a new post in the custom post type "events" is made.

```
function email_members($post_id) {
global $wpdb;

$usersarray = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT user_email FROM wp_users");
$users = implode(",", $usersarray);

if( ( $_POST['post_status'] == 'publish' ) && ( $_POST['original_post_status'] != 'publish' ) ) {
    $subject = 'Event Reminder';

    $post_url = get_permalink($post_id);
    $post_title = get_the_title($post_id);
    $event_date = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'ch_event_date', true );

    $message = "APAC Ministries Event Reminder for: ".$post_title."\n\n";
    $message .= "Date: ".$event_date;

    wp_mail($users, $subject, $message );
  }
}

add_action('publish_th_events', 'email_members');
```

However, the `$event_date` is always empty. I tried running this code in a different file and it works:

```
global $post;
$test = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ch_event_date', true);
echo $test;
```

I have also tried using `global $post;` and using `$post->ID` as the ID. I have also tried getting the terms, and it displays fine. I'm just having trouble displaying the meta.

Any alternative solutions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: This may sound stupid, but did you try adding `echo $event_date`?

Comment: Why do I have to echo it if I'm appending its value to `$message`? Also, I tried adding an if-else statement which displays the word "Empty" if `$event_date` is empty. And it shows "Empty" T_T

Comment: Because php can be screwy every now and again. Its all I could think of off the top of my head, only because `get_the_...` statements only return the value. Something isn't adding up...when I get by my computer I'll try and help some more.

Comment: Show your `do_action('publish_th_events', ....`

Comment: I suspect that `'publish_th_events'` is passing a post object, not a post ID.

Comment: It's passing the ID. I can display `$post_id` in my email and it's the correct ID.

Comment: @user1526570 when you say "empty" specifically is it an empty string or array?

Comment: And the meta data has been stored already? I guess not. Try to get the value directly from the POST data -> $_POST['ch_event_date'] Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

`get_post_meta` as seen [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/post.php#L1724) is nothing more than a wrapper for `get_metadata`. Now when you say the meta you're getting back, if its not null but rather an empty string, it means you're hitting the end of `get_metadata` as seen [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/meta.php#L299). With true defined as the third variable of your get_post_meta call, you should be seeing an empty string if this is the case. If you change it to false, you should see an empty array.

Now to the issue of why you're at the bottom of get_metadata.

Based on what I can see, the only way to get there is that you *don't* actually have a post_meta_field called "ch_event_date" defined for that post_object.

Perhaps, try doing this right above your call to get "ch_event_date" as a test:
`update_post_meta($post_id,'ch_event_date', 'Chris figured it out');`

Then dump that get_post_meta call.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I just tried it out on a site I'm developing and using something similar to below, I was able to do what you're having trouble doing, using a custom field.

```
$message = print "APAC Ministries Event Reminder for: " . $post_title . "\n\n";
$message .= print "Date: " . $event_date;
```

The only reasoning that makes any sense to me is using the `get_the_...` is only returning the values for future use, not for displaying them. In the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) it appears that the function automatically prints or echoes the `$users` and `$subject`

If you look closely at your test where it displays the date properly, you `echo` it. I hope this helps!

Comment: I added "print" but it produces an error: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/wishbone/public_html/demo/apacministries/wp-content/themes/apacministries/functions.php:416) in /home/wishbone/public_html/demo/apacministries/wp-admin/post.php on line 222` and `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/wishbone/public_html/demo/apacministries/wp-content/themes/apacministries/functions.php:416) in /home/wishbone/public_html/demo/apacministries/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 875`

Comment: Check out this [thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-4) or change it to echo them? This is an odd case...